# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus

> Using $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n+1}(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n}(x)dx$, show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

I don't see how to utilize those two definitions to prove this. How do I involve cosine and sine?

Comment: It's easier to use the gamma function and not the integrals!

Comment: This is useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585882/find-int-0-frac-pi2-sin2n1xdx/1585886#1585886

Comment: This is standard using Wallis integral, and the solution is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals

Comment: Can someone prove it?

Comment: @Thomas I don't see it proved in the Wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

To facilitate the notation, we will write 
$$
I_{n}:=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n}(x)dx
$$
You can show, for example with integration by parts, that:
$$
I_{2n+2}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}I_{2n}
$$
and:
$$
I_{2n+1}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{2n-1}
$$
Then, using induction, you may prove:
$$
\frac{I_{2n+1}}{I_{2n}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}
$$
So it is enough to prove that the limit of the quotient of the integrals is $1$. I don't now much about calculating such limits, but I guess you could do it using the squeeze theorem:

Because $\sin^{n+1}(x)≤\sin^{n}(x)$ for all $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, we have $I_{n+1}≤I_{n}$. Therefore:
$$
\frac{I_{2n+1}}{I_{2n}}≤1
$$
Furthermore, by using the above mentioned recurrence relation, we can see that:
$$
\frac{I_{2n+1}}{I_{2n}}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{I_{2n-1}}{I_{2n}}≥\frac{2n}{2n+1}
$$
Thus:
$$
\frac{2n}{2n+1}≤\frac{I_{2n+1}}{I_{2n}}≤1
$$
And by squeeze theorem:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{I_{2n+1}}{I_{2n}}=1
$$